# Parity private blockchain, gain ether

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

I started parity node in dev network using this command

```
parity --jsonrpc --jsonrpc-port 8180 --chain dev --author * --geth
```

the author is the address of my parity node client

and then I start mining by starting ethminer

```
ethminer -F http://localhost:8180
```

I supposed that after mining started my account can gain some ether but I didn't received any ether.

Can you help how can I run private ethereum blockchain using parity and gain some ether for some testing on sending transactions and deploying smart contracts?

Answer (score 1):

The address created with an empty phrase contains a lot of tokens that can be used to send transactions, it can be created with UI or a RPC call (make sure to enable the `--jsonrpc-apis parity_accounts` API):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_newAccountFromPhrase","params":["","password"],"id": 1}' localhost:8545
```

or using the UI:

1. Go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser and go through the initial setup.
2. Click on "NEW ACCOUNT".
3. Pick "Recover account from recovery phrase".
4. Leave the phrase empty and fill the other fields.
5. Go to the newly created account and click "TRANSFER" to conduct your first transaction.
6. Confirm with a password picked earlier.
7. A block should get sealed (see in the log) straight away.

No need to create a custom genesis.

*Note: I work for Parity.*

Comment: I get `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found","data":null},"id":1}` error when using curl and UI version seems to have changed,  `ACCOUNTS -> +RESTORE`. I have tokens now but I still can't mine to my author address using `ethminer`, why? it's 6 blocks deep now.

Answer (score 0):

To get ethers in your private chain you could preallocate them in the genesis file ([json file](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/Demo-PoA-tutorial.md#3-complete-the-chain-specification))

```
"accounts": {
     "0x003449c9ddabad287e4665ce56b121605dfbd39c": { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962" }
                }
```

you can check by running

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0x003449c9ddabad287e4665ce56b121605dfbd39c", "latest"],"id":1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
```

Comment: The dev chain is already preloaded on the account which can be recovered from an empty phrase.